# SwiftUI - ScrollViewReader's scrollTo does not scroll

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview

I have a simple **SwiftUI** list that I want to scroll to a row when a user click on a button. I have copied this code from [hackingwithswift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-scroll-to-a-specific-row-in-a-list). It suppose to work, but it does not do.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            VStack {
                Button("Jump to #50") {
                    proxy.scrollTo(5, anchor: .top)
                }

                List(0..<100) { i in
                    Text("Example \(i)")
                    .id(i)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

---

I tested it on iOS 14.2 both on simulator and a physical device.

I read its [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewproxy/scrollto(_:anchor:)), but there is not much info.  So how to scroll to a row, for example, row 50?

Comment: Hmm... works fine with iOS 14.1. I observe reporting too many defects in 14.2 SwiftUI...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`ScrollViewReader` works only with:

- Explicit use of `ScrollView`
- List of identifiable collection

It does not work with `List` of `Range<Int>` unless you set its `id` explicitly.

**Set id explicitly.**

```
// List(0..<100, id: \.self)

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            VStack {
                Button("Jump to #50") {
                    proxy.scrollTo(5, anchor: .top)
                }

                List(0..<100, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text("Example \(i)")
                    .id(i)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// ForEach(0..<50000, id: \.self)

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(0..<50000, id: \.self) { i in
                        Button("Jump to \(i+500)") {
                            proxy.scrollTo(i+500, anchor: .top)
                        }
                        Text("Example \(i)")
                            .id(i)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            VStack {
                Button("Jump to #50") {
                    proxy.scrollTo(50, anchor: .top)
                }

                List{
                    ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                        Text("Example \(i)")
                        .id(i)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What changed???

Comment: Daniel, in the original answer, the button that scrolled to 50 had scrollTo(5... instead of scrollTo(50...  This is a problem, because if the view is already on the screen, then swiftUI doesn't do much to scroll to the new place.