# SwiftUI scroll to horizontal list item

Tags: swiftui

I'm able to scroll to a vertical List item using ScrollViewReader proxy.

I tried doing something similar with Horizontal list, but it totally messed up the view.

Any suggestion, how this can be done ?

tia!

```
   ScrollViewReader { proxy in
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators:false) {
            ForEach(0..<items.count) { index in
                Text(items[index].title)
                    .id(index)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("tapped \(index)")
                    }
            }
            .onAppear{
                proxy.scrollTo(selectedIndex, anchor: .center)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - ScrollViewReader's scrollTo does not scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64976866/swiftui-scrollviewreaders-scrollto-does-not-scroll)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ScrollView` will not layout your views in a row just because you've specified `.horizontal` scrolling.

You need to specify `HStack`/`LazyHStack` explicitly inside `ScrollView`.

Another problem you may have encountered is that the scrolling position is not accurate, this can be fixed with `DispatchQueue.main.async`:

```swift
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        HStack { // or LazyHStack
            ForEach(0..<items.count) { index in
                Text(items[index].title)
                    .id(index)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("tapped \(index)")
                    }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                proxy.scrollTo(selectedIndex, anchor: .center)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Phil Dukhov. This works for me. Especially ``` DispatchQueue.main.async {}``` block did the work.
For others help:
In my case, I was navigating from one View to another (SwiftUI) and in the onAppear block, I was trying to scroll to the selected item. Just adding the above line works for me.